# Finding Gunicorn Config File

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

I am on ubuntu and using nginx and gunicorn. I know one must create a gunicorn config file when setting up gunicorn, but I was not the original developer and have no idea where it is stored. Is there any way to find out where the config file is stored besides blindly searching?

Comment: The are several ways to configure gunicorn. In many implementation it just runs from command line arguments.

Comment: Is there any way to find out then what way it is configured? I am trying to change the gunicorn timeout period, but have no idea how it was setup

Comment: The first place to look is how it is actually started, then `grep` the code for `gunicorn`.

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect answer but there are a few indicators for the location of an existing Gunicorn Config file.

Codehunter.CC (And [gunicorn docs](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#config-file)) say:

> As far as default names go, Gunicorn will look for a configuration
> file named gunicorn.conf.py in the directory where Gunicorn is
> executed

So you may look for the configuration file in that directory in case it has been put there.

Alternatively you can do a search using a Linux Find command.

For example you may go to your home directory `cd ~`
and then use this command to search this folder and every existing subfolder:
`sudo find . -name gunicorn.conf.py`
Using sudo allows you search files using administrative rights.

Hope this is helpful